# Latency issue in messages passed through Hive MQTT broker

Tags: performance, hive, mqtt, latency, hivemq

I have a Hive MQTT server deployed as docker (with 8GB storage) on a CentOS machine.
Through a simulator, I am sending 10k messages sequentially on a fixed MQTT topic on this server.

It takes 5.37s to send and 9.62s to receive the last message on a docker Hive MQTT deployement.

The same 10k messages take 5.98s when Hive MQTT is deployed on the machine.

In both the cases, there is a big latency issue.
The same latency when measured with other MQTT server is very low, all messages are recieved in lesser than 2s.

Please help as to what can be the reason for so much latency while using Hive MQTT..

Comment: Do you mean 8GB of Storage or 8GB of RAM? Also if RAM how have you configured the JVM heap to use all 8GB?

Comment: Please give more details to be able to help you: What edition/version of HiveMQ are you using? Which QoS are you using? Where runs the "simulator", on the same machine, a different machine or over the internet? How many MQTT clients are you using? Does "sending sequentially" mean that you are waiting for the ack? How do you measure the time durations, when do you start and stop the timer?

Comment: Also, what does "9.62s to receive the last message" mean? Is there a subscriber client? How do you measure this? Correct latency testing methodology is described in this post https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2018/08/video-monitor-end-to-end-latency-of.html